# Ruby Merge Two Hashes With Selective Overwrite

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have two different hashes with same keys:

```
a = {"word"=>"phileas", "character"=>1, "location"=>0, "adjective"=>0, "noun"=>1}
b = {"word"=>"phileas", "character"=>0, "location"=>1, "adjective"=>1, "noun"=>0}
```

And I want to merge these two hashes into following format:

```
a = {"word"=>"phileas", "character"=>1, "location"=>1, "adjective"=>1, "noun"=>1}
```

I tried this code:

```
a.update(b){|key,oldval,newval| !oldval.is_a?(String)  ? oldval | newval :  oldval+newval}
```

But it gave me the following:

```
{"word"=>"phileasphileas", "character"=>0, "location"=>1, "adjective"=>1, "noun"=>0}
```

The problem is I cannot create a condition on String value. When it merges, it merges the String value as well. I want String value remain and merge the rest. If the other values are bigger than 0, I want that value to remain. You can think these values as boolean or flag.

Comment: What do you mean by merging the hashes? What is the problem with String value being merged? It is not clear at all what you are doing.

Comment: You get `"phileasphileas"` because you do String concatenation in case `oldval` is a String => `oldval + newval`. Don't you just want to keep `oldval` in that case?

Comment: what of doing `next if oldval.is_a? String`

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers in the merge, I want to keep oldval if it is String.

Comment: **If the other values are bigger than 0, I want that value to remain.** -- If both are bigger then `0`, then let me know..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p a.merge(b) { |k,v1,v2| v1.is_a?(String) ? v1 : v1 | v2 }
# => {"word"=>"phileas", "character"=>1, "location"=>1, "adjective"=>1, "noun"=>1}
```

It actually makes more sense to check if your key is of type `Fixnum`, so you are sure it supports the logical OR operator, and leave other values unchanged:

```
p a.merge(b) { |k,v1,v2| v1.is_a?(Fixnum) ? v1 | v2 : v1 }
# => {"word"=>"phileas", "character"=>1, "location"=>1, "adjective"=>1, "noun"=>1}
```